# How to Dynamically Deserialize json Object?

Tags: c#, json, .net

I am trying to make my code more simpler and avoid redundant code. I have a function that will accept an object, and a json response from an API call. I want to pass in the object, and response, and have it deserialize dynamically. is this possible? i already have classes created for each of the Json files below.

```
private object ParseObject(object obj, string response)
{
     try
     {
         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<obj>(response);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

Different types of JSON Files

```
{
  "jobStatus": "4",
  "jobStatusDescription": "Job is complete",
  "resultSet": [
    {
      "equipmentInitial": "BNSF",
      "trainId": "S MEMSCO 1 15"
    }
  ],
  "rowCount": "1"
}
```

Second One

```
{
  "intermodalUnits": [
    {
      "attachedIntermodalUnits": [
        {}
      ],
      "carInitial": "INIT",
      "carKindCode": "K18 ",
      "carKindTypeCode": "K",
      "carNumber": "A1B2",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can accomplish this, but why would you not simply define types for each of your JSON payloads and be explicit when deserializing?  I ask because that is the correct solution 99% of the time, and I'm dubious that you're in the 1% here.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I do have them defined. I wwas just trying to see if I could simplify this by passing in the JSON, and the specific object i want it to deserialize to

Comment: It is the same as JObject.Parse(json). You don't need to invent a bike again.

Comment: Look into using [generic type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) on your method.

Comment: @Dedicated it does not appear to me that your `ParseObject` method accomplishes anything useful and makes things worse than simply using `JsonConvert` by itself since it swallows useful exceptions and doesn't allow you to specify the type.  But Jesse is correct that you could at least improve your `ParseObject` method by having it take a type parameter and passing that type to `JsonConvert`.

Comment: And all this method adds then is swallowing exceptions? Sounds great.

Comment: Parsing and Deserializing are two different things.  You do not add clarity to anything by using them interchangably

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, first one needs to create types that match your JSON (please include this in your Minimal Reproduceable Example the next time.

```
public class Job
{
    public const string TestJson = @"
    {
      ""jobStatus"": ""4"",
      ""jobStatusDescription"": ""Job is complete"",
      ""resultSet"": [
        {
          ""equipmentInitial"": ""BNSF"",
          ""trainId"": ""S MEMSCO 1 15""
        }
      ],
      ""rowCount"": ""1""
    }";

    [JsonProperty("jobStatus")]
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("jobStatusDescription")]
    public string JobStatusDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resultSet")]
    public List<ResultSet> ResultSet { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rowCount")]
    public string RowCount { get; set; }

}

public class ResultSet
{
    [JsonProperty("equipmentInitial")]
    public string EquipmentInitial { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trainId")]
    public string TrainId { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class IntermodalUnit
{
    public const string TestJson = @"
    {
      ""intermodalUnits"": [
        {
          ""attachedIntermodalUnits"": [
            {}
          ],
          ""carInitial"": ""INIT"",
          ""carKindCode"": ""K18 "",
          ""carKindTypeCode"": ""K"",
          ""carNumber"": ""A1B2""
        }
      ]
    }";

    [JsonProperty("intermodalUnits")]
    public List<InnerIntermodalUnit> IntermodalUnits { get; set; }
}

public class InnerIntermodalUnit
{
    [JsonProperty("attachedIntermodalUnits")]
    public List<object> AttachedIntermodalUnits { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("carInitial")]
    public string CarInitial { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("carKindCode")]
    public string CarKindCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("carKindTypeCode")]
    public string CarKindTypeCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("carNumber")]
    public string CarNumber { get; set; }

}
```

With that, to answer your question (as asked), I'd do something like this:

```
private static Lazy<MethodInfo> DeserializeGenericMethod = new Lazy<MethodInfo>(() =>
    typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "DeserializeObject" && m.ContainsGenericParameters).FirstOrDefault());

private object ParseObject(object obj, string response)
{
    var deserializeSpecificMethod = DeserializeGenericMethod.Value.MakeGenericMethod(obj.GetType());

    try
    {
        return deserializeSpecificMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { response });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It uses reflection to invoke `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` for the type you specify.

You'd call the method something like this:

```
var result = ParseObject(new Job(), Job.TestJson);
var result2 = ParseObject(new IntermodalUnit(), IntermodalUnit.TestJson);
```

But a better solution would look like:

```
private object ParseObject(Type objType, string response)
{
    var deserializeSpecificMethod = DeserializeGenericMethod.Value.MakeGenericMethod(objType);
    // the rest of the method the same.
```

In that case, you'd call it like this:

```
var result3 = ParseObject(typeof(Job), Job.TestJson);
var result4 = ParseObject(typeof(IntermodalUnit), IntermodalUnit.TestJson);
```

Note that this way, you don't have to use a (possibly newly created) object that really is never used.

It would also make sense to make `ParseObject` a generic method:

```
private object ParseObject<T>(string response) where T : class
{
    var deserializeSpecificMethod = DeserializeGenericMethod.Value.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
    // the rest of the method the same.
```

You might even keep both the version that takes the `Type` and the generic version (with one calling the other) to allow your users a choice

**BUT**

Neither of these is a good solution.  As others have pointed out, all you are doing is swallowing the exception; your users will be left in the dark when something goes wrong.

Instead, consider a variation on the reasonably standard `TryXxx` pattern.  Something like this:

```
private bool TryParseObject<T>(string response, out object obj) where T : class
{
    var deserializeSpecificMethod = DeserializeGenericMethod.Value.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

    try
    {
        obj = deserializeSpecificMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { response });
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = ex;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that now your users can check for errors.  If there is no error, then the `out` parameter is the newly deserialized object.  If there is an error, then the `out` parameter is the exception that was thrown.

Here's what calling this would look like:

```
var test1 = TryParseObject<Job>(Job.TestJson, out var result7);
var test2 = TryParseObject<IntermodalUnit>(IntermodalUnit.TestJson, out var result8);
var test3 = TryParseObject<IntermodalUnit>("badJson", out var result9);
```

**BUT** again...

None of this really buys you very much.

> *Postscript*:
> After I finished this, I realized that reflection isn't needed on the generic (`<T>`) versions of this code.  But, I'll let you fix that...